# rotate news in the webpage

Tags: joomla1.6

I am creating a website in joomla1.6 and using tr_neutrino template.In the website,I want the  news will rotating contineousely.and when the mouseover the news the rotation should be stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure who makes that template but there are numerous news rotating extensions. Your selection will depend on whether you are using the core Joomla com_content or if you are using a CCK type extensions like K2 or Zoo.

Look in the JED for tons of options -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-showcase